# How to use initialize FormModel with request.post and model instance.

Tags: python, django

So I basically have this code:

```
@render_to('hello/home.html')
def home(request):
    info = Info.objects.get(pk=1)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InfoForm(request.POST, instance=info)
    else:
         form = InfoForm(instance=info)
   return {"info": info, "form": form}
```

aaand it doesn't work as I guessed it would be. 
If I initialize form with ONLY either model instance or POST, it works, but not when both.
Is there a (nice?) way to create form with data populated from model instance, and update it with data from request.POST?

Comment: Have you looked at [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)?

Comment: What exactly is not working here? What are you trying to do? Usually you use the `POST` data to save an updated version of the instance, so for example you'd check `form.is_valid()` and then do `form.save()` in the POST block here.

Comment: It should as is according to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method. When you say it doesn't work is there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are writing is already in the framework.

### urls.py

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from myapp.forms import InfoForm
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^info/(?P<pk>[-_\w]+)/update/$', UpdateView.as_view(model= Info,template_name="hello/home.html",form_class=InfoForm), name='info_update'), 
)
# you might need to include a success url in the **kwargs i.e. success_url="/thankyou/"
```